# The rule of the 3 sigmas ---- how many times multiply the sigma to get 85%?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

$\sigma c=\sqrt{\overline{R}(\sigma S)^{2}+\overline{S^{2}}(\sigma R^{2})}$
where,

$\sigma c$ --- the buffer stock --- needed for maintaining the risk
of stockouts, is used by logistitians

$\overline{R}$ --- the mean of the reserves

$\overline{S^{2}}$ --- the mean of the production

$(\sigma S)^{2}$ --- the square of the std. deviation of the production
series

$(\sigma R^{2})$ --- the square of the std. deviation of the reserves

With this value of the stock buffer i am able to assure 84% of the
stockouts. If i wanted 97.6% of the cases i would calculate for the
value of 2 sigmas instead of one like in the equation. Now these percentages
are given values......but what if i wanted to have the stock buffer
to cover a custom percentage not only the cases where sigma is 1,
2 or 3....but 1.2 for example. The problem is i need to get how many
times i have to multiply the sigma in order to get 85% of the stockouts
covered by the possible stockouts.

Comment: Your values are obtained from the cumulative standard Normal distribution.  For instance, in `R` you can use `pnorm` by typing (say) `pnorm(1.2)`.  The answer you will get is 88.5%.  The function `qnorm` is the inverse; *e.g.*, `qnorm(0.85)` yields the answer 1.036: that's the multiplier to use for 85% coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an application like the one [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html).  If you do, be sure to select "Up to Z" (it starts on "0 to Z" by default, which is not what you want) in the application window.  If you move the cursor to Z=1 or Z=2, you can easily verify that it reproduces the 84% and 97.6% (actually, it's 97.7%, I believe) values that you have already quoted.  Alternatively, to obtain more accurate values, you may also scroll further down in the link above, and they also provide a table where you can just read off the numbers that you need.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to find it by the CDF of normal distribution but is very hard, here is s.m.th more about this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145087/how-to-calculate-the-integral-in-normal-distribution). Thanks a lot for the help you saved my day :)